# Multi-database providers support

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I am going to work now on an eclipse plugin which works fine with a derby database and the job consists of adding the Multi-database support for this application (with database configuration wizard).

My question is: what is the best design pattern to follow to achieve this project and for better maintainability in the future ?

Is there any POC source code I can start with?

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of open ended, but I'll take a stab.

I prefer using JNDI for Data Sources.  This way, the container maintains the datasource connection, your application just uses a simple string to define the JNDI name and obtains a connection from the container.

There are a few ways of doing this, and I'm not sure what container you are using (servlet like Tomcat, or EE like glassfish), but they should all support them in some way.

Also, might want to remove your dependency on Eclipse to setting up your datasource connections and rely on something that's more portable, be it a framework such as Spring, or abstracting your datasource connections in code yourself through a factory class.

Comment: Thanks dardo,

First, our application is an eclipse plugin, so no container at all. Just import a lot of data from binary files and load them into database then work directly with database data to generate reports,...
Second important point is that the performance is a big concern in our application, so I do not prefer to user ORMs....

Apparently, the appropriate way will be using DAO (JDBC) and factory pattern. Is there any other alternative in this direction ?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Ah it's an eclipse plugin! I read that wrong, my apologies.  If you want to use straight SQL, yeah, JDBC is the way to go.  Just make sure your DAO is injected with the DB connection to separate concerns.  Also, keep in mind, just because you are using JDBC to generate the report, doesn't necessarily mean it it will be faster than using an ORM, especially considering you can have the ORM run custom SQL.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer dardo!! Can you please give a more concrete explanation of "DAO is injected with the DB connection"? sorry for that but didnt get the point.

Comment: Basically you want your DAO blind to the datasource.  What I mean by this is, your DAO doesn't know what the backend database is, how it's getting the connection to it, etc.  All it knows is that it has a connection to a data source, and it's using it to query.  The reason you want this is for A) easier testing (mocking the datasource to test specifically what you want), and B) in case you change your data source later, it allows for easier swapping.  In the java world this came into affect with Java CDI (JSR 330), Spring and Google Guice both implement this API.

Comment: Mind accepting the answer so it gets off the unanswered tag =)